# terraform aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment SSL PolicyNames

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform, setting

Using terraform, does anyone know how to set a **predefined** SSL Security Policy for an ELB, from within the **aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment** resource?

I've tried various permutations of parameters, branching out from something like the below, but have had no luck.
```

```
setting {
    name = "PolicyNames"
    namespace = "aws:elb:listener"
    value = "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"
}
```

```

Can this be done using the setting syntax?

regards
Michael

Answer (score 13):

Following works for classic ELB, LoadBalancerPorts is also required to set to 443 for the predefined policy to take effect.

```
setting {
  namespace = "aws:elb:policies:sslpolicy"
  name      = "SSLReferencePolicy"
  value     = "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"
}

setting {
  namespace = "aws:elb:policies:sslpolicy"
  name      = "LoadBalancerPorts"
  value     = "443"
}
```

Comment: This answer really should be marked as accepted.  Changing the TLS policy requires both the SSLReferencePolicy and LoadBalancerPorts options.  This is the answer that helped me.

Comment: I got the error "Policy names must only contain alphanumeric characters or dashes." without the `LoadBalancerPorts` setting. The documentation for these options from AWS is unbelievably poor.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
setting {
    name = "SSLReferencePolicy"
    namespace = "aws:elb:policies:policy_name"
    value = "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"
}
```

> SSLReferencePolicy
>
> The name of a **predefined security policy** that adheres to AWS security best practices and that you want to enable for a SSLNegotiationPolicyType policy that defines the ciphers and protocols that will be accepted by the load balancer. This policy can be associated only with HTTPS/SSL listeners.

Refer:

[aws:elb:policies:policy_name](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elbpolicies-custom)

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for that - but no luck there.   I get this error message.

Reason: Policy names must only contain alphanumeric characters or dashes.

Regards
Michael

Comment: So that's something else. At least the message you provide proved this `aws:elb:policies:policy_name` works. Can you check if you can replace with  simpler policy name?

Comment: Hey - yep I did give that a crack right away.  I receive the same error regardless of the "value" of the name. IE if it is a valid value, with dashes, or simply an invalid valid with only text, the result is the same.   IE

Comment: setting {
    name = "SSLReferencePolicy"
    namespace = "aws:elb:policies:policy_name"
    value = "ELBSecurityPolicyWithNoPunctuation"
 }


still gives
* 2017-08-10 03:29:20.656 +0000 UTC (e-6pscazhkrg) : Updating load balancer named: awseb-e-6-AWSEBLoa-QXCM4ZPPQDJF failed Reason: Policy names must only contain alphanumeric characters or dashes.
* 2017-08-10 03:29:20.927 +0000 UTC (e-6pscazhkrg) : Failed to deploy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got an answer from AWS Premium Support:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elb:listener:
    PolicyNames: sslpolicy
  aws:elb:policies:sslpolicy:
    LoadBalancerPorts: 443
    SSLReferencePolicy: 'ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01'
```

Basically, `aws:elb:policies:policy_name` is not a valid namespace, which is why you get an error like "Updating load balancer named: awseb-e-6-AWSEBLoa-QXCM4ZPPQDJF failed Reason: Policy names must only contain alphanumeric characters or dashes" - `policy_name` needs to replaced with a name of your choice (in my case sslpolicy) and then listed as a policy in the `aws:elb:listener` namespace. The `LoadBalancerPorts` entry is needed to make the new `SSLReferencePolicy` actually take effect.

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
setting {
    name = "SSLReferencePolicy"
    namespace = "aws:elb:policies:SSLReferencePolicy"
    value = "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"
}
```

Comment: Adding some explanation to why it works will help more then just saying it works.